# AWS bucket policy- permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to give a user from another AWS account access to the bucket `itv-twitterstg-archive` and I've added the following bucket policy. They say they are getting a permission denied message. Can anyone see any issues with this policy or recommend anything else I can try? (ps, I've changed the name of the bucket for this example). Also should a buckets policy come into effect as soon as you save it?

EDIT** To summarise, I want the user twitterstg-backup from account AWS account 456456615374 to be able to perform these actions:

```
 "s3:GetObject*"
 "s3:PutObject"
 "s3:PutObjectAcl"
 "s3:DeleteObject"
"s3:GetBucketLocation"
 "s3:GetBucketAcl"
  "s3:ListBucket"
```

.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "twitterstg backup policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow read/write of Objects within archive from specific user",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::456456615374:user/twitterstg-backup"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::itv-twitterstg-archive/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow read/list of archive Bucket from specific user",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::456456615374:user/twitterstg-backup"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::itv-twitterstg-archive"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your policy as listed in the Question is **working perfectly fine for me!**

Here's what I did:

**In Account A:**

- Created an IAM User (`User-A`)
- Obtained an Access Key & Secret Key for the User

**In Account B:**

- Created an Amazon S3 bucket (`Bucket-B`)
- Added your policy as the Bucket Policy, with some changes:

  - As `Principal`, I inserted the ARN of `User-1`
  - As `Resource`, used the name of my Amazon S3 bucket
- Uploaded an object to the bucket

I then used the credentials from `User-A` to list the contents of `Bucket-B`:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket-b --profile user-a
```

I also copied a file to `Bucket-B`:

```
aws s3 cp foo s3://bucket-b --profile user-a
```

**Bottom line:** It's working fine. You should investigate why your users are having a problem. You should also try to reproduce their situation (eg by trying it for yourself).

Comment: Agreed, form what I have read I should be able to specify user from another account in the bucket policy. Answer accepted as the other give misleading information.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the principal should be **Account-B** (i.e. the other account) value.

```
"Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::456456615374:user/twitterstg-backup"
            },
```

**Example:-**

```
 "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:root"
         },
```

**Second Account:-**

Should setup the IAM user with appropriate policy as well.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::itv-twitterstg-archive"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

[Refer this full documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html)

**How to find account id:-**

Please follow the below steps to get the account id of Account-B.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by the Account-B-ID bit, do you mean 456456615374? i.e. the other account number?

Comment: I have added the screenshot on how to get the account id of Account-B. Please follow the steps.

Comment: But I already know the account number of the other account, it's in the question (456456615374), or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Then, just change it to root at the end e.g. "arn:aws:iam::456456615374:root". Once this is done, the account B has to do the setup at their end. Follow the account B setup steps described above. Detailed doc link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html