# why the bucket policy is not set I created new also

Tags: amazon-web-services

There is problem in bucket.when we check the uploaded file in bucket and click on link the output will be "Access Denied" message display

Comment: you need to review your permissions/policies

Comment: Here's a well-answered question similar to yours: [AWS bucket policy- permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844490/aws-bucket-policy-permission-denied?rq=1)

Comment: Your question needs to be expanded to show the policy you are trying to use and what result you expect it to have.  It is not clear what you are asking.